# ElasticSearch Stats Aggregation custom field value for max/min

Tags: elasticsearch, statistics, aggregation

Is it possible to retrieve Stats Aggregation with custom field value of max/min document?

Eg. imagine example from [ElasticSearch Stats Aggregation documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) is there possible to retrieve for example name of student with max/min value of grade? (we assume that beside grade there is student name in document).

Is it even possible? What if ElasticSearch gives us multiple documents with max/min value?

Answer (score 2):

No - it's not possible to get a max value **and** the rest of the document in a single query.

You would need to do two queries - the first to get the max value, the second to return documents that have a matching value.